# button click event not firing after second click in ext.widow

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

Hi i'm veeeery new comer in ext js. I wanna ask this.. 
I have a window in ext js and there is a button there, called "btnSearchArea". I have to send parameters before the button is clicked to show a window again in a tree view based on parameters.

**But the problem is. the "btnSearchArea" only can click at once,** when i change the parameter on the first window and click again the button. this button doesn't firing.

this is my code
in HTML

```
 <div id="sa-employeedetail-form" class="x-hide-display">
    <table class="sa-form sa-form-field" style="margin: 10px">
        <tr>
            <td>Job Title :
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("JobTitleID")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brand :
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("BrandID")
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <table class="sa-form sa-form-field" style="margin: 10px">
        <tr>
            <td>Search : </td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("ddlSearchArea", items)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtSearchAreaP" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Area :
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("AreaID", "", new { @class = "sa-required" })
                <button id="btnSearchArea" class="btn-lookup">...</button>
                <br />
                <label id="AreaName"></label>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and js

```
$("#btnSearchArea").click(function () {
    rows = $(this).closest("tr");
    var winArea = Ext.getCmp('winArea');
    if (!winArea) {
        winArea = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            id: 'winArea',
            title: 'Area List',
            width: 400,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            autoScroll: true,
            contentEl: 'sa-area-form',
            closeAction: 'close'
        });

        ShowLoading("sa-body", "Please Wait ...");
        $.post(root + "Area/GetAreaByParam", { FieldName: $("#ddlSearchArea").val(), Area: $("#txtSearchAreaP").val() }, function (data) {
            try {
                areaFB = data.Area;
                areaFBVersion = data.Version; 
                rootNodeArea = GenerateAreaObject(areaFB);
                tvHtml = "";
                GenerateAreaFBTreeView(rootNodeArea);
                treeviewAreaFB = "<ul>" + tvHtml + "</ul>";
                //draw tree
                $("#sa-area-form").html(treeviewAreaFB);
                $("#sa-area-form").dynatree({
                    checkbox: false,
                    selectMode: 3,
                    minExpandLevel: 4,
                    onDblClick: function (node, event) {
                        if (node.data.key != "0") {
                            $("#AreaID").val(node.data.key);
                            $("#AreaName").html(node.data.title);
                            $(".areaForm").show();
                            winArea.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
                HideLoading();
                $(".areaForm").show();
                winArea.show();
            } catch (ex) {
                MsgErr(ex);
            }
        })
    } else {
        $(".areaForm").show();
        winArea.show();
    }
});
```

any suggestions ?. Many Thanks :)

Comment: I would recommend not mixing up jQuery and extjs. You can make everything with ExtJS without jQuery. I can't determine your problem by the code itself atm. Is the button replaced by a new one? If so then the click event will not fired again because your button isn't the same object as before and the click event isn't assigned anymore. You have to reassign the click event then.

Comment: It sounds like you might be accidentally replacing your button with a new, visually idential button. This would cause your button to lack the click handler that you attached to the original button.  Can you create a fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) to duplicate this?  And I agree with @Tyr that you don't seem to need jquery here and mixing them unnecessarily makes things trickier to debug than they have to be.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion Tyr. i have done it by not mixing it. many thanks :)